# Any way to make a portal with water in it without spawning in flowing water blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

So I needed to make a portal with flowing water in it to be the filling material. The problem is that I don't want to spawn in flowing water blocks 'cause if I can avoid spawning in something I don't.

So is there any way of making water not flow to the sides in vanilla MC nowadays?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to achieve. Can you perhaps add some screenshots to show what you're after?

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct, you want something like this:

1. [image]
2. [image: List item]
3. [image]

There is no better way for doing this without commands / MCEdit.

Maybe in 1.13 there will be a trick to to this.

However, I do not see any point in your question, as I can't imagine any situation where this would be useful.